# Create Multidimensional Array in PHP with Dynamic Data

Tags: php, for-loop, associative-array

I am preparing a menu system for a restaurant which provides food on a monthly basis. This is my problem:

There are different packages that the restaurant offers. Each package consists of a number of servings each day. For example, package A serves 3 times a day, whereas package B serves 2 times a day. The online ordering system that I am building is a multi-page ordering system divided as per the number of days. So for 20 days, there are 20 pages. Once the selection of one day is completed, I want to store the selection in a multi-dimensional array. Refer to the below structure for reference.

```
$selection_package_a = array( 
   "Serving_Day1" => array (
      "Serving_1" => Pizza,
      "Serving_2" => Salad, 
      "Serving_3" => Smoothies
   ),
   "Serving_Day2" => array (
      "Serving_1" => Salad,
      "Serving_2" => Juices,    
      "Serving_3" => Fruits
   ),
);

$selection_package_b = array( 
   "Serving_Day1" => array (
      "Serving_1" => Pizza,
      "Serving_2" => Salad
   ),
   "Serving_Day2" => array (
      "Serving_1" => Salad,
      "Serving_2" => Juices
   ),
);
```

"Serving_Day1" to "Serving_Day20" depends on the number of days served during a month. So if the package serves only 10 days a month, then "Serving_Day10" will be the last field.

Within "Serving_Day1", "Serving_1" and so on depends on the number of servings stored in the database.

Taking the answer of @yarwest a step forward, I have pasted the progress till now. I guess it is just one more step to acheive the desired output.

```
$meals_selected_array = [];

$total_meals_array = [];

if( $num_row_packages >= 1 ) {
    while($row_packages = mysqli_fetch_array ($result_packages)) {
        $package_id = $row_packages['package_id'];
        $package_name = $row_packages['package_name'];
        $servings_count = $row_packages['servings_count'];
        $days_served = $row_packages['days_served'];

        //repeating it based on the number of days_served
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $days_served; $i++) {
            //how to define/declare $total_meals_array['day_' . $i]            

            //adding user selection for the day in $meals_selected_array array
            for ($y = 1; $y <= $servings_count; $y++) {
                $meals_selected_array["meal_id_day_" .$i] = "Not Available";
                $meals_selected_array["meal_code_day_" .$i] = "Not Available";
                $meals_selected_array["meal_type_day_" .$i] = "Meal";
            }

            //what to do either here or after the below loop in order to add $meals_selected_array above values to $total_meals_array['day_' . $i].
        }          
    }
}
```

When I `$print_r($meals_selected_array)`, I get the result as an Associative Array with perfect labelling and values. Now I just have to add this Associative Array to each day to make my primary Array as a Multidimensional Array.

So my desired output for $total_meals_array is as below:

```
Array
(
    [day_1] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_day_1] => "1" //This will be my Unique ID of selected meal
            [meal_code_day_1] => "Pizza" //This will be the name of meal
            [meal_type_day_1] => "Main Course" //This will be the serving Type
        )

    [day_2] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_day_2] => "4" //This will be my Unique ID of selected meal
            [meal_code_day_2] => "Lemonade" //This will be the name of meal
            [meal_type_day_2] => "Drinks" //This will be the serving Type
        )

    [day_3] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_day_3] => "8" //This will be my Unique ID of selected meal
            [meal_code_day_3] => "Custard" //This will be the name of meal
            [meal_type_day_3] => "Dessert" //This will be the serving Type
        )

)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the number of serving days can change? or is that something that is set for each package?

Comment: They can change. For example, "Package A" is served 10 days a month with 3 Servings per day, whereas "Package B" is served for 20 days a month with 2 Servings per day.

Comment: So it is a set amount of days per package? Everyone that orders "Package A" will get food 10 days?

Comment: Why don't you use normal indexed arrays, with indexes from 0 to 19 in case of 20 days, and then sub arrays indexed 0 to 2 (for when 3 servings that day)? That is the more common way to do this.

Comment: @yarwest is correct. Everyone who selects "Package A" will get food for 10 days.

Comment: @trincot suggestion is that I have already got as Plan B. The only reason I want to use Multidimensional Array is to make the web application easy manageable for my fellow programmers who will be handling the update as well.

Comment: I was not questioning the idea of a multidimensional array. Just the choice of keys.

Comment: Anyway, without actual, concrete input data, and how it will be formatted, there is not much of a question here.

Comment: @trincot, I really appreciate the responses and suggestions here when they are needed the most.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now here is the code that works best in the given situation.

**Situation**
The Order Form is multipage depending on the number of days served based on the package selected. Details of each package are stored in the database with the following fields:

1. package_id (Unique Field)
2. package_name (Name of the Package, e.g. Package A)
3. servings_count (Total Servings in a Day)
4. days_served (Number of Days Served in a Month)

In order to carry forward the selection of meals for each day and serving of that day to store as an Order in the database, I required a Multidimensional Array of PHP that can be defined/populated dynamically.

Expected output is something like:

```
Array
(
    [Day 1] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_1] => Unique ID //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_1] => Meal Name //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_1] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
            [meal_id_2] => Not Available //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_2] => 2 //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_2] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
        )

    [Day 2] => Array
        (
            [meal_id_1] => Unique ID //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_1] => Meal Name //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_1] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
            [meal_id_2] => Not Available //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_code_2] => 2 //to be replaced with user selection
            [meal_type_2] => Meal //prefilled based on the selected package
        )
```

This above array has been created 100% dynamically based on the explained structure and number of servings and days. Below is the code with some explanation.

First, we have to declare two PHP Arrays.

```
$total_meals_array = []; //Primary, Multidimension Array
$meals_selected_array = []; //Meals Details Array to be used as primary array's key value.
```

After doing this, run MySQL query to read packages from the database. Now based on the result, do the following:

```
$total_meals_array = []; //Primary, Multidimension Array
$meals_selected_array = []; //Meals Details Array to be used as primary array's key value.

if( $num_row_packages >= 1 ) {
    while($row_packages = mysqli_fetch_array ($result_packages)) {
        $package_id = $row_packages['package_id'];
        $package_name = $row_packages['package_name'];
        $servings_count = $row_packages['servings_count'];
        $days_served = $row_packages['days_served'];

        //this for loop is to repeat the code inside `$days_served` number of times. This will be defining our primary and main Multidimensional Array `$total_meals_array`.
        for ($y = 1; $y <= $days_served; $y++) {
            //once inside the code, now is the time to define/populate our secondary array that will be used as primary array's key value. `$i`, which is the meal count of each day, will be added to the key name to make it easier to read it later. This will be repeated `$meals_count` times.

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $meals_count; $i++) {
                $meals_selected_array["meal_id_" . $i] = "Unique ID";
                $meals_selected_array["meal_code_" . $i] = "Meal Name";
                $meals_selected_array["meal_type_" . $i] = "Meal";
            }

            //once our secondary array, which will be used as the primary array's key value, is ready, we will start defining/populating our Primary Multidimensional Array with Keys Named based on `$days_served`.
            $total_meals_array["Day " . $y] = $meals_selected_array;
        }
    }
}
```

That's it! Our dynamic Multidimensional Array is ready and can be viewed by simply the below code:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($total_meals_array);
print "</pre>";
```

Thank you everyone, specially @yarwest for being kind enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

## Important note beforehand

It is very unsafe to use `mysqli` functions. They can easily be manipulated with, for example, SQL injections. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp).

#### The solution

You retrieved a package from the database.
The next step is to loop based on the amount of servings and amount of days to create a new array to hold the package.

```
if( $num_row_packages >= 1 ) {
    while($row_packages = mysqli_fetch_array ($result_packages)) {
        $package_id = $row_packages['package_id'];
        $package_name = $row_packages['package_name'];
        $servings_count = $row_packages['servings_count'];
        $days_served = $row_packages['days_served'];

        //Create a new array to hold the servings skeleton
        $servingsArray = [];
        //For every serving add an empty string to the servingArray
        for($i = 0; $i < $servings_count; $i++){
            array_push(
                $servingsArray,
                ""
            );
        }

        //Create a new array to hold the package skeleton
        $selection_package = [];
        //For every day add an servingArray to the package array
        for($i = 0; $i < $days_served; $i++){
            array_push(
                $selection_package,
                $servingsArray
            );
        }           
    }
}
```

This will create an entirely empty array according to the specified structure.

Comment: Your suggestion has brought me a step closer to what I actually want to acquire. Thank you so much. Since I still have not achieved the final result, therefore will need some time to test and vote this answer. I will also edit my question based on this suggestion, if required.

Comment: @MohammedAkhtarZuberi Glad to be of some help. Try to make your question a little more clear if this does not answer it.

Comment: Check my revised question based on your suggestion. Can you please help me to get to the final output?